# Convert linux uptime to well format date

Tags: linux, shell-script, date, uptime

I want to convert uptime to date DD:MM:YY without the ***|*** and I want to put a string like "the computer is on since 23-feb-16"

Comment: What is the output of your uptime command?  What distro are you using?  On Ubuntu, uptime outputs something like "16:25:06 up 47 days, 8:50, 2 users, load average: ..."  The "16:25:06" is the time.  The "up 47 days, 8:50" is up 47 days, 8 hours and 50 minutes"  So, are you wanting to do a date/time calculation on the "47 days, 8:50" or is the output of your uptime different?  Could you edit your question to show the output of the uptime command you are using?

Comment: do you like `uptime -p` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may get it for free from the output of `last reboot`:

```
$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.14.81-i7       Sat Nov 17 23:25   still running
reboot   system boot  4.14.80-i7       Fri Nov 16 09:16 - 15:49  (06:33)

$ printf "On since: "; last reboot | grep "still running" | cut -c 40-56
On since: Sat Nov 17 23:25 

$ printf "On since: " ; last reboot --time-format iso | grep "still running" | cut -c 40-49
On since: 2018-11-17
```

Your `uptime` command might also have the `-s` option:

```
$ uptime -s
2018-11-17 23:25:23
```

Since this format is acceptable to `date -d`, you can reformat the time however you wish like this::

```
$ date -d "$(uptime -s)" "+On since: %d:%m:%y"
On since: 17:11:18
```

Comment: "%d:%m:%y" must be the most perverse date format string I've seen outside of https://xkcd.com/1179 :)

Answer (score 4):

Single command.

```
$ date -r /proc/1 '+The computer is on since %d-%b-%y'
The computer is on since 09-Oct-18
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the *last data modification* of `/proc` directory given by `stat`:

```
date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' "/proc")" +'%F %T %z'
```

Example:

```
$ stat /proc
  File: `/proc'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 1           Links: 188
Access: (0555/dr-xr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-04 16:36:02.016000956 +0200
Modify: 2020-09-04 16:36:02.016000956 +0200
Change: 2020-09-04 16:36:02.016000956 +0200
 Birth: -

$ date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' "/proc")" +'%F %T %z'
2020-09-04 16:36:02 +0200
```